# How can I iterate over easily-differentiated colors? (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, colors

For example: I'm generating a line chart that shows the sales performance of my client's stores. The user will be submitting store numbers (1-200) and the graph will draw a line for each store. I need a function that will return one color for each store and I'd like the colors to look significantly different from one another.

I'm pretty close to having this working.

Here's a jsfiddle that iterates over hues:
http://jsfiddle.net/cabichandani/ub3H9/5/

```
var scale = 200;
var hueSkip = 5;

for (var storeNumber = 1; storeNumber < scale; storeNumber++) {
    var h = storeNumber/scale;
    var color = getColor(h);
    var colorString = getColorString(h);
    $("#store-list")
        .append('<li style="background-color:' + 
                colorString + 
                ';">Store: ' + 
                storeNumber + ' hue:' + 
                h.toFixed(3) + ' color:' + 
                colorString + '</li>');
}

function getColorString(hue) {
    var color = getColor(hue);
    return "rgb(" + color[0] + "," + color[1] + "," + color[2] + ")";
}

function getColor(hue) {
    var huePercent = hue * 100;
    var hueSkipAmount = hueSkip * huePercent;
    var newHuePercent = (huePercent + hueSkipAmount) % 100;
    var newHue = newHuePercent / 100;

    return hslToRgb(newHue,1,0.5);
}

/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
}

/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}
```

I have this concept called "hue skip" that tries to skip over colors that look too similar.

With a hueSkip of 5, I can graph stores 1-6 together and they are easily-differentiate red-yellow colors. But If I put 10 and 11 on the same graph, they look like nearly the same shade of green.

I'd like to improve the function to dish out more easily-differentiated colors, or just take another approach entirely.

Comment: I think you'd be better off skipping around the color circle in HSV or HSL space, and each time you loop back to the starting point you scoot a little in or out (increase/decrease saturation or lightness). So skip by like 120 degrees. That way adjacent colors will be kind-of complementary.

Comment: Also note that almost all modern browsers understand "hsl()" colors (IE8 and below don't).

Comment: I thought I was skipping around the color circle in HSL. I like your idea of skipping by 120 and making it into more of a spiral, though.

Comment: Have you looked at adding point shapes, that will help differentiate them.  But really no matter what coloring/shapes you add, too many lines will make the graph worthless.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it'll be pretty silly if they put too many stores on one graph, but I'd like to give this my best effort.

Comment: @Chris yes I figured that out when I actually looked at your code :)  If you use one of the online "color picker" sites, they're all about finding complementary hues around the color wheel.  You could adapt some of those ideas.  [Here is one that I like a lot.](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the code,  i would separate the color palette creation from the rest of the code, and store this palette inside an array.
This way you can test separately the colors that you get for different values.

Below i created palette by spreading hue on all 0-360 range, except i skip a part of the green, since all greens are very similar. I switch saturation and luminosity one time on two from (90,80) to (65, 55). You might want to switch in between 3 couples of (saturation, luminosity) to get more changes.

http://jsbin.com/UlOgiSuZ/1/edit?js,output

[image]

```
function createPalette (colorCount) {
  var newPalette = [];
  var hueStep = Math.floor ( 330 / colorCount ) ;
  var hue = 0 ;
  var saturation = 95 ;
  var luminosity =  55 ;
  var greenJump  = false ;
  for ( var colorIndex=0; colorIndex < colorCount; colorIndex++ ) {
    saturation = (colorIndex & 1) ? 90 : 65;
    luminosity = (colorIndex & 1) ? 80 : 55;
    newPalette.push( hslToRgbString (hue ,saturation, luminosity ));
    hue += hueStep ;
    if (!greenJump && hue >100) {
      hue+=30;
      greenJump = true;
    }
  } 
  return newPalette ;   
}

// dummy context2d used for hsl -> rgb conversion
var dummyContext = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

function hslToRgbString(h,s,l) {
   dummyContext.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + h +',' + s + '%,' + l +'% )' ; 
  return dummyContext.fillStyle ;
}
```

Test code :

```
function drawPalette( palette, context, x, y, w, h ) {
  context.strokeStyle = '#000';
  context.lineWidth = 1 ;
  for (var i = 0; i < palette.length; i++ ) {
    context.fillStyle = palette [i];
    context.fillRect ( x+i*w, y, w,h );
    context.strokeRect ( x+i*w, y, w,h );
  }
}

// draw some palettes to see how they look
var ctx = document.getElementById('colorCanvas').getContext('2d');

var paletteCount = 17;
for (var i=0; i < paletteCount; i++ ) {
  var myPalette = createPalette(i) ;
 drawPalette ( myPalette, ctx, 0, i *24,20, 20 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something related some time ago, I iterate on every element by the color range and change it by incrementing the hue.
http://pastebin.com/NN7YbbEs

"think you'd be better off skipping around the color circle in HSV or HSL space"

This do exactly that. Also, I got this algorithm with better gamma correction, but I don't remember anymore the source, I will post this here because it could be of use to someone.

```
function transformHSV(I, H, S, V) {
    var VSU = V * S * Math.cos(H * Math.PI / 180);
    var VSW = V * S * Math.sin(H * Math.PI / 180);
    var ret = [];
    I = rgb(I);
    ret[0] = (0.299 * V + 0.701 * VSU + 0.168 * VSW) * I[0] + (0.587 * V - 0.587 * VSU + 0.330 * VSW) * I[1] + (0.114 * V - 0.114 * VSU - 0.497 * VSW) * I[2];
    ret[1] = (0.299 * V - 0.299 * VSU - 0.328 * VSW) * I[0] + (0.587 * V + 0.413 * VSU + 0.035 * VSW) * I[1] + (0.114 * V - 0.114 * VSU + 0.292 * VSW) * I[2];
    ret[2] = (0.299 * V - 0.3 * VSU + 1.25 * VSW) * I[0] + (0.587 * V - 0.588 * VSU - 1.05 * VSW) * I[1] + (0.114 * V + 0.886 * VSU - 0.203 * VSW) * I[2];
    return ret;
}
```